# Explain in MySQL of key_len in this table

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a table that has a column:

`| last_name     | varchar(1000) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |`

I created an index on this column:
`CREATE INDEX lastname_idx ON employees(last_name);`

When I do `EXPLAIN` for a `SELECT` that has a `WHERE` condition on the `last_name` I see:
`key_len = 769`.

If I am not wrong the `key_len` shows the bytes used from the index value.
Since the index is on `last_name` which is `varchar(1000)` why is the `key_len=769`?
Shouldn't it be `1000`?

Comment: If I create an index like that in an InnoDB table (not an MyISAM one), I get a warning:`Warning | 1071 | Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`, which might have something to do with that...

Comment: @Wrikken:Seems you are right. Did not notice the warning.

Answer (score 2):

The default row format for InnoDB stores only the leading portion of a string colum, up to 768 bytes, on the page with other columns.  Any excess is stored on "blob pages" in another segment of your tablespace.

InnoDB uses the same storage method for VARCHAR, BLOB, TEXT, VARBINARY, etc. (all the "variable length" datatypes).  For more storage details, see  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/

It appears that InnoDB automatically assumes an index prefix length equal to the portion of the column it can store inline.  Are you using MySQL 5.6?  I don't remember seeing this behavior on earlier versions (it would simply complain, and you had to declare an index prefix length).

The key_len reported by EXPLAIN always includes a couple of extra bytes when you use varchar.